# How do I get the code take X and plug it into the print statement?

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Weight {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Make scanner to allow user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    //Ask for gender
    System.out.println("What is your gender (Male/Female)?: ");
    //Store gender as string
    String gender = input.nextLine();
    //Ask for weight
    System.out.println("What is your weight (to closest lb)?: ");
    //Stores weight as integer
    int userWeight = input.nextInt();

}

public void genderAndWeight (String gender, int userWeight) {
    //int femaleWeight = 0;
    int maleWeight = 30;
    //Determine whether to use male or female int variable

    if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"))
        {
        userWeight -= maleWeight;
        }
}
public String conditions(int userWeight)
{

    if(userWeight<100)
    {   
        String X = " underweight";


    }
    else if(100 <= userWeight && userWeight <= 130)
    {
        String X = " average weight";

    }
    else if (userWeight > 130)
    {
        String X = " overweight";

    }
    else System.out.println("You suck at typing.");

    System.out.println("You are" + X);
}
```

}

I'm trying to make this code find whether someone is under, average, or overweight, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the variable correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure this code would even compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your methods should probably be `static` (otherwise, they require an instance of the class). Regardless, and to your question, you need to make sure `X` has *scope* (so it's visible). Something like,

```
public static String conditions(int userWeight)
{
    String X = ""; // <-- declare and initialize X
    if(userWeight<100) {  
        X = " underweight";
    } else if(userWeight <= 130) {
        X = " average weight";
    } else if (userWeight > 130) {
        X = " overweight";
    } else {
        System.out.println("You suck at typing.");
        X = " unknown";
    }
    System.out.println("You are" + X);
    return X; // <-- you need to return String.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the variables in your main functions and the functions genderAndWeight and conditions, what happens when you call the functions with the variables you have in main?

```
conditions(userWeight);
genderAndWeight(gender, userWeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually creating new variables each time inside your if statements which go out of scope once you leave the if block. To fix your code, remove your declaration of X and put outside all the if statements and make sure your method declaration is static. like so...

```
    public static String conditions(int userWeight)
    {
            String X = "";

            // and then you continue with you if statements and make sure not to redeclare X, just use it
    }
```

You need to understand scoping in java. A variable scope is the region of the program where that variable is accessible. When you declare a class, any variables you declare out of any method has a class scope(with class scope here i don't mean like static variables, i mean it can be accessed by all methods in that class). If you declare a variable inside a method, it is called a local variable and it is known only to that method. If you try calling that variable in another method you get an error. Also there is block scope, that is any variables you declare in a block will only be accessible to that block, no code out of that block even in the same method will be able to access that variable. Also local variables declaration are placed before statements that use them. Let me demonstrate with examples

```
    public class Test
    {
        int classScope;// this variable has class scope, it can be accessed by all methods in this class

        public void someMethod()
        {
                int localScope = 1;// this is a local variable, it is only accessible inside this method 

                if (true)
                {
                        int blockScope = 0; // this variable has block scope
                } 
                System.out.println(blockScope); // this will cause an error because variable blockScope is not visible here
        }

        public void anotherMethod()
        {
                System.out.println(localScope); // this will cause an error, because variable localScope is not visible here.
        }
    }
```

Note: local variables must be initialized before they are used, as opposed to instance variables which have a default value.

Comment: Thanks for breaking that down, still getting used to Java!

Comment: am glad i could help